# IGMP 2.0 snooping switch timeout

Tags: switch, igmp

Suppose a host computer has joined a multicast group 239.0.0.50 via IGMP 2.0.  As per the IGMP 2.0 spec, when the host computer receives either a general query on 224.0.0.1 or a group wide query on 239.0.0.50, it is supposed to set a random delay timer and wait till the timeout before it sends out a membership report. If during this timeout period, it receives a membership report from some other host claiming to be a member of the group, then, there is no further need of sending out the membership report itself and it can just cancel the timer.

Is the above still the correct IGMP behavior for a host today? I suspect that the switch is timing me out (this happens in a certain prod environment and I will be able to confirm the suspicion only next week) and I heard a suggestion that I should always be sending out a membership report.

(Just for clarification, the host is not a standard/linux box, but a custom non-linux box)

Thanks